# How to call first component from second component in blazor

Tags: blazor

I need:
[image: Button in Main page]

I try:
[image: Button in First component]

I only manage to call the first component from the second one when the button is inside the first component. But I need to move the button to the main page and display it regardless of which component is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either a cacading or service based State object as the component glue.

Here's how to use a cascading state object based on the list/editor context.

First our State object.

```cs
public class MyPageState
{
    public PageState State { get; private set; } = PageState.List;
    public event EventHandler<PageState>? PageChanged;
    public int RecordId { get; private set; }

    public void ShowList()
    {
        State = PageState.List;
        RecordId = 0;
        PageChanged?.Invoke(null, State);
    }

    public void ShowEditor(int recordId)
    {
        State = PageState.Editor;
        RecordId = recordId;
        PageChanged?.Invoke(null, State);
    }
}
public enum PageState
{
    List,
    Editor
}
```

The `List.razor` component.

I'm guessing this is something similar to what you are doing.  Note it either shows or hides itself based on the State.  It registers an event handler on the State's `PageChanged` event so it can render, and either hide or show itself, on a state change.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@if (this.pageState.State == PageState.List)
{
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-8">
            Information about record 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => OpenEditor(1)">Open Record 1</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-8">
            Information about record 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => OpenEditor(2)">Open Record 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private MyPageState pageState { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.pageState.PageChanged += OnStateChanged;
    }

    private Task OpenEditor(int id)
    {
        this.pageState.ShowEditor(id);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, PageState state)
    {
        if (state == PageState.List)
            this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
     => this.pageState.PageChanged -= OnStateChanged;
}
```

`Editor.razor` is basically the same.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@if (this.pageState.State == PageState.Editor)
{
<div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col">
            Showing Record: @this.pageState.RecordId
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="CloseEditor">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="CloseEditor">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private MyPageState pageState { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.pageState.PageChanged += OnStateChanged;
    }

    private Task CloseEditor()
    {
        this.pageState.ShowList();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, PageState state)
    {
        if (state == PageState.Editor)
            this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
     => this.pageState.PageChanged -= OnStateChanged;
}
```

And then the parent, in my case `Index.razor`

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<CascadingValue Value=this.pageState>
    <List />
    <Editor />

</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private MyPageState pageState = new();
}
```

This is pretty simplistic, but demonstrates the patterns and basics you'll need to apply to your application.